# Existing array values in a textbox

Tags: php, arrays, textbox

I have a long array and I want to display its values in a textbox in PHP.

```
if($platform !=0) {
        $mask = get_masks($platform);
        $options =array() ;
        $temp= array();
        $options[0] = "Please select";
        foreach ($masks as $mask_){
            $options[$mask_[0]] = $mask_[1];
            array_push( $temp, $mask_[0] ); 
            print_r($mask);
        }
$form->addElement(new Element\Textbox("Masks :", "mask", array("onchange" => "this.form.submit()", "value" => $mask)));
```

I know I can do this with HTML,but I must use PHP.

Comment: You can try it as `"value" => $mask` to `"value" => implode( " ", $mask)`

Comment: In the textbox in appears now : Array Array.

Comment: And it gives me the error   Array to string conversion